# Why am I getting this error with a PHP cURL request to the GitHub API when it works fine in Postman?

Tags: php, api, curl, github, http-headers

I have a valid OAuth token that I'm using to make GitHub API requests to retrieve information about my private repos.

By referencing the GitHub API documentation (https://developer.github.com/v3/), I'm able to use the token to make valid requests from Postman about my private repos with the following headers (note that the token below is not my real token):

```
Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json
Authorization: token 5c67da5c67f5d67ac5ff5acdf675facbe875t86a
```

However, when I try to use the PHP cURL code below to make the same API calls, I get back the following error message:

```
Request forbidden by administrative rules. Please make sure your request has a User-Agent 
header (http://developer.github.com/v3/#user-agent-required). 
Check https://developer.github.com for other possible causes.
```

Why am I getting this message, even though I'm sending over valid headers?
The GitHub URL linked in the error message even says the following:

> We request that you use your GitHub username, or the name of your
>   application, for the User-Agent header value.

I'm sending my GitHub username as the value for the `User-Agent` header, but it doesn't change anything.
What am I doing wrong?

PHP cURL code:

```
  $ch = curl_init('https://api.github.com/repos/GitHub-username/repo-name/contents/directory-in-repo');

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Accept' => 'application/vnd.github.v3+json',
    'Authorization' => 'token 5c67da5c67f5d67ac5ff5acdf675facbe875t86a',
    'User-Agent' => 'GitHub-username'
  ]);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

  $json = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

  echo $json; // This outputs the error above.
```

---

**Edit #1**:

Based on the comment from jake2389, I tried using a real user-agent string, but it still didn't work. Specifically, for the `User-Agent` header, I tried my browser's current user-agent string (the following), but I still got the same error:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.119 Safari/537.36
```

I then tried the exact user-agent string that jake2389 recommended, and I got the following response:

[image: GitHub error]

I have no clue why one (valid) user-agent string versus another produces two different results, but all the same, neither works.
I'm still not sure what to do.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried setting it to a [valid](http://www.useragentstring.com/) [User-Agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent)? Like `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.1`

Comment: Yes, I did, jake2389, but it still didn't work. Please see Edit #1 above for the details. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

After days of banging my head against the wall and being confused by the GitHub API error message, I finally figured out the problem.

The problem was that the array I was using for the `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` `curl_setopt` function call was wrong. Specifically, it shouldn't be an associative array, it should be an array of string values with the header key-value pairs separated by colons.

As such, the following code worked for me:

```
<?php

  $ch = curl_init('https://api.github.com/repos/GitHub-username/repo-name/contents/directory-in-repo');

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json',
    'Authorization: token 5c67da5c67f5d67ac5ff5acdf675facbe875t86a',
    'User-Agent: GitHub-username'
  ]);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

  $json = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

  echo $json; // This outputs the proper JSON.
```